# Why did Rey not change her clothes for 6 years (three movies)?

Tags: star-wars, plot-device, costume, rey

Why was Rey’s character made so unhygienic by making her wear the same clothes the entire time?
I shiver every time I think how she must have smelled.
And if she did change, where on Earth did she carry her wardrobe?

Comment: Assuming she didn't wear different clothing (she did) what prevents her from having several basically identical outfits? After all, why would a scavenger care about having different styles of clothing? If she had exactly one and only one (because maybe she could only afford one?) why not clean it and wear it every day?

Comment: it would crumble in pieces with all the action she is doing within few days.

Comment: Rey has only been onscreen for about 6 to 9 hours over 6 years of fictional time, or only about  1 divided by 8,766, or 0.000114 of that fictional time.  So it is making a big leap to assume that she never changed her clothing in that time.

Comment: @M.A.Golding getting 25 points shows I am on to something. Besides, I can use your logic, each scene is spread over a long period of time, with the same cloths, ergo, she did not change them, at all. 
She was probably stinking the entire Millennium Falcon the whole time.

Comment: Your 25 points are 25 negative points. What they mean is that your question is one of the most poorly received on the site. Specifically, number 6.

Comment: @Adamant that is what you claim. 25 point is 25 point, this is simple math, even in the Starwars univers math works the same.

Comment: Do you understand a negative sign?

Comment: @Adamant what do you mean "negative sign"? I did not give any "negative sign" to anybody.

Answer (score 18):

She did change her clothes...

## *The Force Awakens*

[image: Close up of Rey in the Tent on Jakku in her tan wrap clothes holding her staff]

## *The Last Jedi*

[image: Close up of Rey on Ahch-To with a white top on and sleeveless grey woollen jacket and grey wrapped arms]

## *The Rise of Skywalker*

[image: Close up of Rey on a desrt landscape in her white wrap clothes]

Comment: And I daresay that they didn't feel the need to show that there would be rudimentary bathing and washing facilities at the very least.

Comment: I actually wonder how she changed her clothes between Episode 7 and 8, since they take place back to back. If she had spare clothes with her on the Falcon for Episode 8, why revert to what she wore basically in 7?

But didn't Han basically wear the same clothes in 4-6?

Comment: @StealthRabbi she changes her clothes at then end of 7 in the little time skip.

Comment: Side note, as I understand it, she was going to have heh hairstyle changed for Episode IX, but it would have complicated using the old Leia footage.